# Testing Tomcat's JDBC Pool Connection

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, jmx, monitor

Is there a way (such as through the use of JMX/MBeans) to test a Tomcat server's JDBC pool connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use JMX beans, you can look for this bean:

```
Catalina:type=DataSource,context=/[context],host=[hostname],class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="[your JNDI name]"
```

That bean has a `getConnection()` method that returns a `javax.sql.Connection` object. Remember to call `close()` on it when you are done.

Comment: Okay, I saw this, but wasn't sure if it actually checked the JDBC pool, or just the database connection. Thank you.

Comment: It will give you a JDBC connection ... from the pool. If you really want to look at the pool itself, check out the various attributes of that same MXBean.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which version of Tomcat you are using and what connection pool, so I feel free to assume you are using DBCP. In that case you can access a lot of the status values from the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`. You will have to do it from inside of your web application. Probably, the least invasive way is to throw in a JSP page that gets your pooled data source from JNDI, queries BasicDataSource for status values and displays them in a simple HTML table.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question re: MBeans.

Comment: The OP asked for "a way". The proposed way certainly qualify.

Comment: I appreciate all responses and suggestions! I will look into your proposal, Pidster. Thank you!